# 3 digit random number in C#

Tags: c#, .net

Is there a better way to generate 3 digit random number than the following:

```
var now = DateTime.Now.Ticks.ToString(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
string my3digitrandomnumber = now.Substring(now.Length - 7, 3);
```

Thanks..

Comment: What kind of distribution do you want? Do you want to get `007`?

Comment: Date/time information is not random. It is strongly tied to the current date and time :) See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.random.aspx for something better.

Comment: 001, 010, 100 should all be okay..

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Yes - your current code isn't *random* at all. It's based on the system time. In particular, if you use this from several threads at the same time - or even several times within the same thread in quick succession - you'll get the same number each time.

You should be using [`Random`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.random.aspx) or [`RandomNumberGenerator`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.cryptography.randomnumbergenerator.aspx) (which is more secure).

For example, once you've got an instance of `Random`, you could use:

```
int value = rng.Next(1000);
string text = value.ToString("000");
```

(That's assuming you want the digits as text. If you want an *integer* which is guaranteed to be three digits, use `rng.Next(100, 1000)`.)

However, there are caveats around `Random`:

- You *don't* want to create a new instance each time you use it; that would also be time based unless you specify a seed
- It's not thread-safe

So ideally you probably want one per thread. My [article on randomness](http://csharpindepth.com/Articles/Chapter12/Random.aspx) talks more about this and gives some sample code.

Comment: But what does the Random class do else?

Comment: @Venson: It maintains state between calls. So you *initially* create it either with a seed or with the current time, but after that the time is irrelevant.

Answer (score 6):

```
int r = (new Random()).Next(100, 1000);
```

Comment: Note that the second parameter of `Random.Next` is exclusive, so it should be `Next(100, 1000)`.

Comment: `new Random()` on the same line is not a good idea. Call it twice quickly can get same "random" value.

Comment: @weston - That would only be a a problem if its called multiple times within the same second ( say a for loop ).

Comment: @Ramhound Yes. That's what I am saying "Call it twice quickly". Once a second is fine, the seed is probably generated from milliseconds at least.

Answer (score 4):

You can use the `Random` class and call `Next(10)` three times.

Comment: Or perhaps `Next(900) + 100`

Comment: @MikeChristensen, that would never return 000-099 would it?

Comment: @AbeMiessler - Ah yea when I think 3 digit number, I think 100-999.  I guess that's just me.

Answer (score 1):

Well, firstly that's an odd setup you have there, why do you first get the date?

You should use this to get a number of 3 digits (less than 1000).

```
Random rand = new Random(); // <-- Make this static somewhere

const int maxValue = 999;
string number = rand.Next(maxValue + 1).ToString("D3");
```

The `maxValue + 1` is because the paramter for `Random.Next(int)` is an exclusive upper bound, meaning that the number returned will always be less than the parameter. It can never be equal to it.

Comment: Since you're creating a new `Random` each time this is almost as bad as using the date.

Comment: @Servy Well, that depends on how often the function is called. I changed it anyway, since I agree it's good practice.

Comment: If the interval in which the function is called is truly "random" then the code in the OP will work just fine.

Answer (score -1):

```
new Random.NextDouble() * 1000
```

Comment: could return values < 100, which are not 3 digits long.